# Does this paragraph have any weird or wrong sentences?

Tags: writing

I'm writing a job recommendation letter for a friend of mine. There's a personal part about our friendship. I would like to know what could be improved. We're not native english speakers and I don't know if this stack exchange is suited for this. Here's the paragraph:

Me and John Doe are friends for more than 10 years. We lived a lot of life experiences together... We already were coworkers, friends of fun, of trouble, of adventures and trip partners. I really trust him. John likes to taste new foods, always open to meet new friends and new places, his desire to discover this world its a nice thing to see. He likes to walk, to drive and loves the sunshine. John is very practical, determined and positive person. These were the first 10 years of friendship... And i know we will have a lot of 10 more.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We can help with specific questions about English. If you edit your question to focus on one sentence or phrase that you are worried about and explain why you think it might not be correct, we may be able to reopen your question.

Comment: First of all, thanks for explaining how this stack exchange works. Is there any document explaning how to write questions? I made this question on Android app and didn't find any guideline besides stack exchange description

Comment: At the bottom of the page there is a help link. Unfortunately the [help] doesn't have a mobile version, so it is a little hard to read on a mobile. I will get you some more links when have time.

Comment: [This meta question about proofreading](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/is-this-question-really-proofreading) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to completely rewrite your tribute, I would make some grammatical and other changes (italicised) so it reads like this :

> *John Doe and I have been* friends for more than 10 years. We *have shared* a lot of life experiences together... We were already
>   coworkers, friends *in fun times*, *in* trouble, *on* adventures and
>   *trips*. I really trust him. John likes to taste new foods, *is* always open to *making* new friends and *visiting* new places. *His*
>   desire to *explore* this world *is* a nice thing to see. He likes to
>   walk, to drive and loves the sunshine. John is *a* very practical,
>   determined and positive person. These were the first 10 years of
>   friendship... And *I* know we will have *many more*.